# Not able to manually type a password when AutoFill functionality is enabled with two textfields

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uikit

[image]

I have two textfields namely Password and Confirm Password. The problem is that if I have autofill password functionality enabled from Settings App, I can type password manually via the keyboard in the Password field but if I then go to the Confirm Password field, it automatically fills in the strong autofill password. Hence, I cannot type a password manually in both the fields.

I am using RxSwift but hopefully that doesn't have any impact on this. All I have done is:

```
passwordTextField.isSecureEntry = true
passwordTextField.textContentType = .newPassword

confirmPasswordTextField.isSecureEntry = true
confirmPasswordTextField.textContentType = .newPassword
```

Even tried setting one of the field's textContentType to .password and the other one to .newPassword, but it doesn't work. I do want both autofill and manual typing functionality. I can fill in password manually in one field but when I tap the other field, both fields change to strong password automatically.

Comment: Which field did you set to .password? The confirm password field or the password field?

Comment: password field to .password and confirm password field to .newPassword